# Energy comparison, evaporate water vs compress air, same mass

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

I would like to compare the energy requirements of the 2 following tasks:

1. Total energy to evaporate 1 litre of water at normal atmospheric pressure at normal temperature?
2. Total energy to compress air into a 1 litre container so that the compressed air had a mass of 1kg? What air pressure would atain this mass?

If its too hard to calculate could you give an estimate?

Comment: I think you would need to specify the air's temperature as well. Regarding the water: you won't need to exert any energy. The water will evaporate by itself.

Answer (score 1):

For (1): the energy required to vaporise a liquid is known as the [enthalpy of vaporisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy_of_vaporization), or alternatively as the latent heat of vaporisation. For water at room temperature this is about 44kJ per mole, and a mole of water is 18g.

For (2): the density of air at room temperature and pressure is about 1.2 kg per cubic metre, so 1kg of air is 1/1.2 or about 0.83 m$^3$. Assuming the air behaves as an ideal gas the pressure can be calculated using [Boyle's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyle's_law):

$$ P_1V_1 = P_2V_2 $$

so the pressure when you compress you 1kg of air down to one litre is:

$$ P_2 = P_1 \frac{V_1}{V_2} $$

where $P_1$ is one atmosphere, $V_1$ is 0.83m$^3$ and $V_2$ is 1 litre.

The amount of work done in compressing the gas is a bit harder, but I go through the calculation in my answer to [How much work is needed to compress a certain volume of gas?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/37634/how-much-work-is-needed-to-compress-a-certain-volume-of-gas). The work is given by:

$$ W = nRT ln \left( \frac{V_2}{V_1} \right) $$

where $n$ is the number of moles (1 mole of air $\approx$ 28.8g) and $R$ is the [ideal gas constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_constant).

Comment: As you point out in your other calculation, the work of compression is very dependent on the actual process. Isothermal compression will give a lower bound, but the compression of such a small volume of air is likely to be adiabatic.